# TQFT associates a category to a manifold

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, category-theory

> *Any 3d TQFT (topological-quantum-field-theory) associates a number to a closed oriented 3-manifold, a vector space to a Riemann surface, a category to a circle, and a 2-category to a point.*

This is properly well-known in category theory. I learned it from [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0654).

I wish to have someone **sharing their physical explanation and their best understanding about this statement**.

I suppose the higher dim generalization is what [Urs Schreiber](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93183/) describes using codimension surface. I have read [the Phys.SE post: about-the-atiyah-segal-axioms-on-TQFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93183/), but would not mind someone starts from the basic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are maybe three different stages to be distinguished and to be understood here:

**first:** maybe part of the question is why an $n$-dimensional QFT should assign numbers to closed $n$-dimensional manifolds, and vector spaces to closed $(n-1)$-dimensional manifolds. That is what I had replied to [in that other discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/93284/5603) linked to above: the vector spaces assigned are just the spaces of quantum states assigned to a spatial hyperslice of spacetime, the numbers assigned to closed $n$-dimensional pieces of spacetimes are the partition functions, and generally the linear maps assigned to $n$-dimensional pieces of spacetime with boundary are the quantum propagators (the correlators, the [S-matrix](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/S-matrix)) which propagate the incoming states to the outgoing states.

**second:** the question is why one would want to refine this assignment ("Atiyah-Segal-type QFT") to something that also assigns data to $(n-k)$-dimensional pieces of spacetime, for all $0 \leq k \leq n$. The answer to this is that this solves what in physics is known as the "problem of covariant quantization". Namely assigning vector spaces of states to spatial hyperslices a priori means breaking the diffeomorphism invariance of the field theory, after all it involves choosing these spatial hyperslices and assigning data to them in a way that is not a prior build up covariantly.

The whole point of "[extended TQFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extended%20TQFT)" is to solve this "problem of covariant quantization of field theory" by enforcing that the spaces of quantum states which are assigned to codimeninson-1 spatial hyperslices arise from gluing of local data. It's the *[locality principle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local%20quantum%20field%20theory)* of quantum field theory, by which every global assignment must be reconstructible from gluing of local assignments.

Mathematically this is where [higher categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher%20category%20theory) come in: where the ordinary [category of vector spaces](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vect) knows about vector spaces and linear maps between them, hence about the data of spaces of quantum states and of propagators between them, an [n-categorical](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-category) refinement of this would also know how to build spaces of quantum states (which are then promoted from objects to $(n-1)$-morphisms) from local data (namely by composing $(n-1)$-morphisms along $(n-2)$-morphisms).

So in summary: the reason for passing from Atiyah-Segal style QFT which formalizes the assignment of spaces of quantum states to spatial hypersurfaces and of linear quantum propagator maps between them to pieces of spacetime to higher categorical [extended QFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extended%20TQFT) is to fully implement the [locality principle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local%20quantum%20field%20theory)  of quantum field theory in the axioms.

The high-point of this axiomaticts is the [cobordism theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cobordism%20hypothesis) which fully clasifies all fully local ("extended") TQFTs in a rigorous fashion.

**third**: the question then finally is: if an $n$-dimensional fully local (topological) quantum field theory hence is an n-functor $Bord_n \to \mathcal{C}$ from the [n-category of cobordisms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-category+of+cobordisms) to *some* [n-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-category) $\mathcal{C}$ which in its two top dimension degrees looks like vector spaces with linear maps between them, then: what should $\mathcal{C}$ be like in lower degrees?

This is actually a question of ongoing investigation. The [cobordism theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cobordism%20hypothesis) itself allows any [n-category wth all duals](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(infinity,n)-category+with+duals), but many of these will not "look very physical" in fact.

In any case, the point to notice here is that $\mathcal{C}$ is a *choice*. It may -- but need not -- look like suggested above in the question. This is what it tends to look like for [3d TQFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/3d+TQFT) of [Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons%20theory) type. The strongest theorem to that effect is now probably [Douglas & Schommer-Pries & Snyder 13](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fusion%20category#DSPS). See there for more.

Comment: @ Urs Schreiber, Vielen Danke, thanks +1. Get back to you soon.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the category theory part, but the ideas regarding 'numbers' to a 3-manifold and vector spaces to Riemann surfaces comes about naturally in Gromov-Witten theory (see here: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jbland/ma273x_notes.pdf for a nice introduction).

The heuristic recipe (physical explanation) is as follows: Take a closed symplectic (as one does in TQFT) manifold $\Omega$. Look at maps from Riemann surfaces of genus $g$: $R_{g}$, to a smooth space built from $\Omega$ (Like the Grassmannian $\mathbf{G}$). You can now look at the moduli stack of all such maps (i.e, the collection of pseudo-holomorphic curves $\psi$ from $R_{g}$ to $\mathbf{G}$ satisfying some conditions, call this $\mathcal{M}$). This moduli stack $\mathcal{M}$ admits a class field theory, i.e, has some equivalence relations on it $[Z,\tilde~]$ that tells you when two curves are equivalent. This is essential since Riemann surfaces have some strange behaviours, if you have ever studied branch-cuts and things you will know what I mean. Meaning that, given various $g$ you may have degeneracies between them.

One then studies intersection theory on this moduli stack and counts the number of pseudo-holomorphic curves that obey some relationships modulo the equivalence relation $\tilde~$. The intersection theory itself produces numerical invariants, which are useful to describe the topological nature of the manifold $\Omega$. These ideas are very reminiscent of the ideas of de-Rham cohomology, which study differential forms on the manifold $\Omega$ to better understand its topology. This is a very important concept in TQFT, since one would like to know precisely how 'unique' or otherwise their manifold structure is. Computation of these invariants using integrals over $\mathbf{G}$ can be done in principle.

As an example, in string theory, one can imagine that the strings of different kinds can join together to form various topological structures, which on a larger scale represent the different types of particles we observe. To exactly describe all possible configurations of how these strings join it is necessary to analyse these Gromov-Witten invariants to maintain internal consistency (i.e, you cannot have a particle which has two distinct ground state energy levels).

Not sure if that is helpful at all, but I think the study of Gromov-Witten invariants (or Donaldson-Thomas, etc) is what you are after here (see here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gromov-Witten+invariants as well).

Comment: @ Arthur Suvorov, thanks +1, it is good to hear Gromov-Witten invariants here, something not expected at first.

Answer (score 2):

I expect this is somewhat of an axiomatic statement, since the TQFT axioms include the association of a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ to a vector space (or a module) $Z(\Sigma)$, and an element $Z(M)\in Z(\partial M)$ to a manifold $M$. They do not include direct reference to categories. It sounds like the categories are natural extensions to the lower dimensions ($d=0$ and $d=1$).

Comment: @ levitopher, thanks +1. Get back to you soon.